# How To Print This Input For Every Index

Tags: javascript, json

I have the following input, coming from HTML:

```
{
administrator: true,
premium: true,
name: 'John',
city: 'Bucharest'
},{
administrator: false,
premium: true,
name: 'Marry',
city: 'London'
},{
administrator: false,
premium: false,
name: 'Arya',
city: 'Bucharest'
}
```

How can I print every element with city === 'Bucharest' ?

for example:

```
All people from Bucharest are:

John
Arya
```

As to mention, I have tried the following:

```
var users = document.getElementById("oneUser").innerText;

users.forEach(function (user){
                    console.log(user);
                })
```

but it didn't work, the following error occurs:

```
Uncaught TypeError: users.forEach is not a function
```

Also, I tried to user JSON.parse(), but the input is not actually a JSON type (missing " " from first parameter).

EDIT:

```
<p id="oneUser" style="display:none"><%= users %></p>
```

The <%= users %> is an array coming from the mongodb database.

Then, I wanted to assign it to a javascript variable, which is why it is a String now.

```
var users = document.getElementById("oneUser").innerText;
```

Comment: Your variable `users` is a string. The first thing you posted isn't valid Javascript; how is it coming from HTML?

Comment: Actually, I used ejs to get some data from database (mongodb), and this is how it comes. Then I assigned that data to a javascript (frontend) variable to work with it

Comment: Show what the HTML source looks like with its JavaScript as generated from ejs.

Comment: I edited the first post :)

Comment: So it seems you need to somehow parse your string into a valid JS Object. I'd personally probably start by removing any curly braces and splitting the remaining string into a comma-delimited array.

Comment: This is exactly what I did, not elegant work but at least I did it. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Try this -

```
[
   {
      "administrator":true,
      "premium":true,
      "name":"John",
      "city":"Bucharest"
   },
   {
      "administrator":false,
      "premium":true,
      "name":"Marry",
      "city":"London"
   },
   {
      "administrator":false,
      "premium":false,
      "name":"Arya",
      "city":"Bucharest"
   }
]
```

```
 myFilter = (prop, val) => {
      return data.filter(e => e[prop] == val)
 }
```

Usage -

```
myFilter("city", "Bucharest")
myFilter("premium", false)
```

Comment: I can't use filter as "users" is a String in my case, not an Array